# how to fix this autoscrollview without button?

Tags: android, textview, scrollview, runnable

I have a code. this code about auto scroll in scrollview, but the scrollview only run when i press the botton. i want to run without the button . how to fix this??

Code:

```
       final ScrollView scrollView = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.sv);
    Button start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_start);

    final Handler timerHandler = new Handler();
    final Runnable timerRunnable = new Runnable()
     {


        @Override
        public void run() {
            scrollView.smoothScrollBy(0,1);     
            timerHandler.postDelayed(this, 50);   

        }
    };

    start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                timerHandler.postDelayed(timerRunnable, 0);
            }
        });}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you needed auto scroll, you can try this.

```
 scrollView.post(new Runnable() { 
        public void run() { 
             mScrollView.scrollTo(0, scrollView.getBottom());
        } 
});
```

**Method2**

```
scrollView.fullScroll(scrollView.FOCUS_DOWN);
```

**Method3**

```
    scrollview.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        scrollview.post(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                scrollview.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

**ScrollView with Animation**

```
ObjectAnimator animator=ObjectAnimator.ofInt(scrollview, "scrollX",targetXScroll);
animator.setDuration(800);
animator.start();
```

Comment: Let me know whether this answer helps you.